# How do I write a regular expression for gsub that keeps whitespace, letters and numbers but removes punctuation marks?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that achieves the following:

```
General Motors --> General Motors (stays the same!)
Yahoo!         --> Yahoo (remove exclamation point)
Le7el          --> Le7el
Mat. Science   --> Mat Science
```

I tried a simple "/\W+$/", but that catches punctuation at the end of the line only, unfortunately.

Comment: That is because you specified it. `$` anchors the end of the line, so you're trying to match 1 or more non-word characters at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be Unicode-aware then use the "Punct" property:

```
s.gsub(/\p{Punct}/, '')
```

That will work just as well with simple ASCII punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Try `s/[^\w\s]//g`, it should replace all non-word and non-space characters with an empty string.

If needed, specify exactly what you consider valid characters, like `s/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]//g` for instance.

---

OKay, so that's Perl, but it's the <strike>thought</strike> regex that counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
['General Motors','Yahoo!','Le7el','Mat. Science'].map{|e| e.tr('.!','')}
# => ["General Motors", "Yahoo", "Le7el", "Mat Science"]

['General Motors','Yahoo!','Le7el','Mat. Science'].map{|e| e.gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,'')}
# => ["General Motors", "Yahoo", "Le7el", "Mat Science"]
```

Comment: that works, yes. I was hoping for a regex because I want to remove all non word / non whitespace characters.